# NEC Question about laundry area 210.52(f)

Tags: electrical, nec

**210.52(f)** states a **20 amp** circuit must be in the laundry area.

- What is defined as the laundry area?
- My washer and dryer are in my undivided, unfinished basement.  Is my entire basement considered the laundry area?
- Is it just the wall space immediately around the washer/dryer?
- Is there somewhere else in the NEC that specifies this?

Comment: Imagine they want one for the washer(usually 120v), so where the washer is, is the laundry area(where the plug for the washer can reach).  Since a washer needs plumbing supply and drain that is not easy to move, the area is probably quite small.

Comment: Note that I believe that NEC _also_ wants GFCI protection in basements, particularly unfinished basements, so I think you're splitting hairs here, worrying about which part of the basement is the "laundry area".

Comment: IF there is a practical point to this question can you add it to the question please?  If you are doing construction, provisioning a laundry area, that area is exactly where you say it is, and you will provide services right there.  The point of the code is to describe exactly what you must provide, not to limit where you can provide it.   You can always bring a cynical approach to compliance by interpreting words that were not meant to be interpreted.  "The laundry area includes the house next door, there is an outlet there, DONE!".  No.  What exactly is your aim?

Comment: Good reminder about GFCI. I've been doing that without knowing it was required when I've dropped new circuits, but it reminds me that I should fix one outlet that isn't protected... and which does happen to be in the original Laundry Area

Answer (score 6):

"An area containing or designed to contain a laundry tray, clothers washer, or a clothes dryer". That's how an NEC copy I have at hand defines a laundry area in the context of mobile/manufactured homes/parks. It sure sounds like a universally applicable definition of "laundry area" to me.

Answer (score 4):

Typical power cord is ~6 feet long. Can the washer and/or 120V (gas or heat pump) dryer plug in **without an extension cord**? ...Then you're in "**The Laundry Area.**"

Comment: This.  Hopefully if you are building a laundry area you'll provide water, drain, and power all so that standard hoses and cords can work.  If instead you go Clintonesque on the inspector with your definition of "area" you'll probably get a blind date with the inspector's fine-tooth-comb.

Comment: I read that in the voice of the opening narration to *The Twilight Zone*.

Comment: Is it appropriate to flip the code phrasing to say that the washer/dryer must be located within 6ft of a 20A circuit?